# VBA Excel Macro to select range of all Active rows

Tags: excel, vba

I've recorded macro ad successfully running it but need to add dynamics selecting only range of rows, below I pasted and commented some failed attempts.`enter code here`

```
 Sheets("Sheet1 (3)").Select
 Rows("1:12").Select                    
'Rows(1:ActiveCell.Row).Select
'Rows("A1:" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
```

Can you help me to select all active rows, in my case I could have empty in between.

Comment: Do you mean find the last populated row?

Comment: `Rows("1:" & ActiveCell.Row).Select`

Comment: Thanks much BigBen!!! Problem solved.